# Oracle 11g Partitioning Strategy for this table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Database: Oracle 11g

I am working on a greenfield project and designing a database schema. I have an audit table which, as the name suggests,
 will grow to hold huge number of records eventually. Following is the table definition (after pruning the extraneous columns).

```
create table ClientAudit (
    id                number(19,0) primary key,
    clientId          number(19,0) not null,
    createdOn         timestamp with time zone default systimestamp not null
);
```

id is a natural number to be populated by oracle sequence.
clientId is a unique client identifier.
For ease of query by reporting, I am creating a following view as well, which gives the latest record for each client, based on createdOn:

```
create or replace view ClientAuditView 
as
select * from (
    select ca.*,max(ca.createdOn) keep (dense_rank last order by ca.createdOn) 
        over (partition by ca.clientId) maxCreatedOn 
        from ClientAudit ca
) 
where createdOn=maxCreatedOn;
/
```

I am not sure what should be the partitioning key here if I were to partition ClientAudit table.
Should it be ClientId, or CreatedOn?
What should be the partitioning strategy?

Answer (score 0):

Since the selection is on the createdon, i would suggest to have a range partition and also the query should refer to the correct partition based on passed date.

Answer (score 0):

You will not benefit from partition pruning this way. If you plan to store data for a very long time, this will result in view working very slow.

I recommend storing "latestAuditTimestamp" or "lastAuditId" in the clients table or another entity and will re-do the view as following:

```
create or replace view ClientAuditView 
as
select ca.* from ClientAudit ca
where (clientId,createdOn) in (select clientId,lastAuditTimestamp from Clients c)
;
/
```

In the later stage you can optimize it more, by adding range condition for maximum/minimum lastAuditTimstamp in case number of clients goes too high and HASH SEMI JOIN would be used.